# Cubic Reciprocity

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I am currently working through to understand quadratic reciprocity and when working through the problems came across this cubic reciprocity problem.  I have been able to do parts a and b but am unable to completely understand how to proceed with parts c and d.

Proof of c :
=> Suppose $a\equiv c^3 (mod p)$ and g is a primitive root.

Suppose $m=3k$m then $g^m=g^{3k}=(g^k)^3$

Let $g^k=c$ then $c^k= a (mod p)$

I feel as if my approach is not quite correct.
Another approach I have taken is by noticing that $g^k=a=c^3 (mod p)$

I am also not quite sure as to how $p \equiv 1 (mod 3) $ is important.
Any suggestions and clarifications are helpful.[image]

Comment: The importance of $p\equiv1\bmod3$ is brought out by part (d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For c) let me only write the implication I think you struggle with. Suppose that $a\equiv c^3\pmod p$ and $g^k\equiv c$ and $g^l\equiv a$ modulo $p.$ Then we have $g^{3k}\equiv g^l\pmod p$ so $g^{3k-l}\equiv1\pmod p$ and hence $p-1\mid 3k-l$ and as $3\mid p-1,$ the result follows.

For d) proceed as follows: Suppose that $p\nmid a.$ Then by Fermat's little theorem we have $1\equiv a^{p-1}=a\cdot a^{p-2}\pmod p$ so $a\equiv \left(a^{-1}\right)^{p-2}\pmod p.$

Answer (score 0):

A simple criterion for cubic reciprocity:

If $p=1\pmod 3$, then $p=a^2+ab+b^2$ for integers $a, b$. If an integer pair ($a,b$) is a solution, let $c=a+b$. If either $a, b, c=0\pmod {3t}$, then $t$ is a cubic residue $\pmod p$. The converse is not necessarily true, thus no easy methods are known for finding cubic non-residues.